# how much apple pay to opengroup for unix license renewal?

Tags: macintosh, macos, licenses

i see this certificate on open group website
[image: opengroup certificate for mac]

you can checkout this certificate on opengroup website
here : https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/certificates/1190p.pdf

**i want to ask that is apple pay open group to renewal new license every time and how much it cost ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Apple must pay to renew the certificate every year, if they want to keep it active. The current certificate for macOS is [available here](https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/certificates/1210p.pdf).

Renewals cost $400 but the complete fee structure is more complex; see [the Open Brand fee schedule](https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/Brandfees.htm) for details.